# AJAX request not sending request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've got this AJAX request that doesn't work, the url is correct I believe, I've tried multiple different urls and none of them work, so I suppose that's not the problem.

```
$('span').click(function(){
    id = $(this).attr('id');
    if(id != 'undefined'){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:'test/test.php',
            data: {id:id},
            success:function(data){
                    alert(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

When I alert the variable 'id' inside the IF statement it does alert it perfectly, so something is wrong with the AJAX request.

Comment: Any errors in the console or network tabs of debug tools?

Comment: Nothing, the only thing that firebug says is that it failed.

Comment: Check the network tab for more information on why the request failed.

Comment: Change ='undefined' to =undefined because when it's undefined it's not a string. Also, has I'd already been set?? Because if not, it should be initialized by "var id"

Comment: Yeah, the variable is initialized with "var id", and I don't know what just happend, but firebug isn't showing any errors (only that it failed) and it worked for 7 times, without running the "success function", now it's not working again, so I really don't know what is going on :S

Comment: You can be sure `test/test.php` is available by calling it directly in your browser.

Comment: I tried that too, it's working fine.

Comment: Why are you setting a click function *for every single damned span in existence on your page*??

Comment: Because there's only 3 spans on the entire page.

Comment: What is happening in `test.php`? And are you printing/echoing in the correct format (typically json)?

Answer (score 0):

Change `id = $(this).attr('id');` to `var id = $(this).attr('id');`